# Android: Human readable timestamp not generated inside recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve timestamp from firebase database and trying to show it in textview inside recyclerview. The timestamp generated is not in human readable format. It displays like this: {timestamp={.sv=timestamp}}.

Getters and Setters:

```
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    HashMap<String,Object> timestampCreated;
     public Blog(String title,String desp,HashMap<String,Object>timestampCreated) {
            this.title = title;
            this.desp=desp;
            //this.timestam=ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
            HashMap<String,Object> ts=new HashMap<>();
            ts.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    }

     public HashMap<String,Object>getTimestampCreated(){

           if(timestampCreated!=null)
           return timestampCreated;

           HashMap<String,Object> timestampCreatedObj=new HashMap<String,Object>();
           timestampCreatedObj.put("timestamp",ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
           return timestampCreatedObj;
        }

       public void setTimestampCreated(HashMap<String,Object> timestamp){
            this.timestampCreated=timestamp;
        }

        @Exclude
        public long getTimestampCreatedLong(){
            long value=(long)timestampCreated.get("timestamp");
            convertTime(value);
            return value;
        }

     public String convertTime(Long unixtime){
            Date dateObject=new Date(unixtime);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy  hh:mm:ss");
            return dateFormat.format(dateObject);
        }

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
     mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
            mDatabase.keepSynced(true);

ViewHolder:



    public void setTimestampCreated(HashMap<String, Object> timestamp) {
               TextView show_ts = (TextView) mview.findViewById(blog_timestamp);
              show_ts.setText(String.valueOf(timestamp));


           }

Adapter:



    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(
                        Blog.class,
                        R.layout.blog_row,
                        BlogViewHolder.class, mDatabase

                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(final BlogViewHolder viewHolder,final Blog model, int position) {

                        viewHolder.setTimestampCreated(model.getTimestampCreated());


                    }
                };
                mbloglist.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

Image of the database: [database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaiNx.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#format(java.lang.CharSequence,%20long)) util class in Android Package.

```
String humanReadableTime = DateFormat.format("dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm", timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your data as a `TIMESTAMP` in a correct way. Remember, when you set the `TIMESTAMP`, you set it as a `Map`, but when you retrieve it, you retrieve it as a `Long`. So in order to get it right, i suggest you using this method:

```
public static String getTimeDate(long timeStamp){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateTimeInstance();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
        return dateFormat.format(netDate);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "date";
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do we have to call it somewhere inside the code or defining it is enough?

Comment: You can define this method in the class/activity you need or you can define it in a separate class, a helper class. Than you just need to call it using as an argument, the `Long` value that you get from the database.

Comment: I called it inside gettimestampcreatedlong() using getTimeDate(value); The problem still persist.

Comment: Are sure you are getting the value from the right location and you are not missing a child? Can you please show us your database structure?

Comment: It's ok but i cannot see in your code where you query the database. I cannot see the `DatabaseReference`.

Comment: I can see only the declaretion of `DatabaseReference mDatabase`. Where are you using it? Please share the code in which you retrieve the `TIMESTAMP` from the database together with the `mDatabase`.

Comment: Where you define your `DatabaseReference`. Something like this: `DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child()....` and how you are using it.

Comment: 'mDatabase =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");'
' mDatabase.keepSynced(true);' This is how i have used

Comment: Ok, that good but still not the see the listener. `mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent` and so on.

Comment: DatabaseReference newPost = databaseReference.push(); newPost.child("timestamp").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

Comment: Madhu, this is how you set the TIMESTAMP, i asked you to provide me how you get the TIMESTAMP.